# Newly appended select options not displaying title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using ajax to append new options to a multiple select box, but even though I'm trying to add title attributes to them, they don't seem to be displaying at all. Is there something that I'm missing?

[image]

This is done in Coffeescript:

```
$.ajax(
        type: 'get'
        url: '/Filter/LookupClassification'
        data: ( term: inputVal )
        dataType: 'json'
        success: (response)->
            select = document.getElementById('getClassBox')
            select.options.length = 0

            $.each(response, (key, value)->
                option = $(
                    '<option/>'
                    'title': value.toUpperCase()
                    'value': key
                ).text(key + ' - ' + value.toUpperCase())

                $('#getClassBox').append(option)
            )

            $('#selectClassBox option').each((index, value)->
                val1 = $(value).val()
                if $('#getClassBox option').val() is val1
                    $('#getClassBox option[value=' + val1 + ']').remove()
            )
    )
```

Comment: Since when has the `title` attribute been valid for `option`s, and how could it possibly be useful?

Comment: @GrantThomas I'm trying to use it for tooltips on mouseover, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/spB3E/

Comment: It shows up on hover for Chrome 26, IE 10, and Firefox 20.0.1, unless I'm somehow seeing things other people aren't.

Comment: @GrantThomas - Since at least [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-label-OPTGROUP).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario it's interesting that the HTML5 spec doesn't mention "title".

Comment: @Pointy - I think it does. The [<option> element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) accepts [Global Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes) among which we can find `title`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario ah OK well now I feel silly for completely mis-reading that :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `<option>` element can't have a "title" attribute. [See the spec.](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-option-element)

*edit* — by that I mean that while it's fine to add a "title" attribute if you want to, the browser won't pay attention to it like it would to a "title" attribute on a `<div>` or `<button>` element.

*edit again* — also you should probably ignore this since, though it's not in the HTML5 spec, the "title" attribute on `<option>` elements is apparently supported in some browsers.

Comment: They *can* (works in some browsers), but *shouldn't*, said by the spec you provided

Comment: @Ian yes that's true; I'll elaborate.

Comment: I knew what you meant, but for others' reference :)

Comment: And whoa turns out some browsers will do it!  Who knew?  (Well @Baadshah obviously :-)

Comment: Even @Baadhsha also not tested in all browsers mentioned there.I  am sure.I saw him while testing in IE9   :P

Comment: @Pointy would you happen to know of a good tooltip solution for option values that extend far past the width of the parent select box? A few SO solutions said to use the title attribute, but if it's not reliable, is there a more natural go-to solution?

Comment: @SCS well I've never really thought about trying to use tooltips for `<option>` element. Now that mobile devices are so prevalent, I think it's better to devise more explicit informative interface conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write this to add options to your dropdown:

```
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(key + ' - ' + value.toUpperCase(), key);
```

Don't bother about title attributes.

Comment: Would you happen to know what might be my best bet for displaying option values that extend far past the width of the select box? I'm trying to go for the simplest tooltip solution, but it seems using title attributes is not the best idea.